# Moving general fibers of a fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-geometry, automorphisms, galois-groups

Let $X$ be an irreducible projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ admitting a morphism $\pi:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ with connected fibers. We may assume that the general fiber of $\pi$ is smooth.

My question is the following: can we always find a Zariski open subset $U\subset\mathbb{P}^1$ such that the group $Aut(X_U)$, of automorphisms of $X_U = \pi^{-1}(U)\subset X$, acts transitively on the fibers of $\pi$ over $U$?

Comment: To be pedantic: the empty subset is open everywhere. If you mean “on all fibers of $π$ over $U$”, then wouldn’t it be vacuously true for empty $U$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not; it may be that none of the fibres are isomorphic to each other.
 The typical situation is that a given fibre is isomorphic to only finitely many others.